# Famo.us ScrollContainer not scrolling

Tags: javascript, famo.us

```
define(function(require, exports, module){
var View            = require('src/core/View');
var Surface         = require('src/core/Surface');
var ScrollContainer = require('src/views/ScrollContainer');

function ListView(){
    View.apply(this, arguments);
    _createContent.call(this);
}

ListView.prototype = Object.create(View.prototype);
ListView.prototype.constructor = ListView;
ListView.DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {
    data: []
}

function _createContent(){

    var sc = new ScrollContainer();
    var sequence = [];

    sc.sequenceFrom(sequence);

    for (var i = 0; i < this.options.data.length; i++) {
        var surface = new Surface({
            content: this.options.data[i].name,
            size: [undefined, 40],
            properties: {
                borderBottom: '1px solid #000',
                padding: '10px 15px'
            }
        });
        sequence.push(surface);
    };

    this.add(sc);
}

module.exports = ListView;
});
```

As you read from the title, my problem is Famo.us ScrollContainer is not scrolling. The above code is used to add a scrollable list. This module is then included in a PageView. The PageView is included in the MainView which has a RenderController to show or hide the pages. The list is showing along with the data being passed to this module. The only problem is the Scrolling. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `surface` needs to pipe events to the `ScrollContainer`.

```js
    for (var i = 0; i < this.options.data.length; i++) {
        var surface = new Surface({
            content: this.options.data[i].name,
            size: [undefined, 40],
            properties: {
                borderBottom: '1px solid #000',
                padding: '10px 15px'
            }
        });
        surface.pipe(sc);  // Pipe the Surface events to the ScrollContainer
        sequence.push(surface);
    };
```